# Converting values in Athena Presto

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

I have a few things I want to accomplish with Presto. I currently getting some data in the following formats

1. `date 16-Jan-2018`
2. `num 1000`

I want to write a query that can convert these values to

1. `2018-01-16`
2. `1,000`

Answer (score 3):

For the date you could do the following:

```
select date_parse('date 16-Jan-2018','date %d-%b-%Y')
```

For the second field, you would have to split it first with split(string, delimiter), then cast the second array element to INTEGER.

Here is the full answer:

```
SELECT date_parse(date_string,'date %d-%b-%Y') as parsed_date, 
       CAST(
            split(int_string, ' ')[2] AS INTEGER
       ) as parsed_int 
  FROM (VALUES ('date 16-Jan-2018', 'int 1000')) 
    AS t(date_string, int_string)
```